# share twitter link without link?

Tags: html

I am building a twitter link in my page as below

```
<a class="twitter-share-button shareButton twitter popup" href="http://twitter.com/share?text=I just entered the GOLD RUSH competition to win $10,000 Bullion! Enter now for your chance to win! http://goo.gl/2Z58q9"  data-text="I just entered the GOLD RUSH competition to win $10,000 Bullion! Enter now for your chance to win!" data-count="none" data-url="https://www.facebook.com/DiscoveryChannelAU" title="TWEET" target="_blank"><img src="32919/images/twitter.png"  alt="" /></a>
```

However, every time the twitter share link opens it brings up a page where the current page URL is displayed too.  I do not want to share my url (media....etc). **Is that possible ?**

Comment: Is this what don't want displayed: "www.facebook.com/DiscoveryChannelAU"?

Comment: No I just want to display http://goo.gl/2Z58q9. It also displays the current page where it is being rendered from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=YOUR-URL-HERE&text=YOUR-TEXT-HERE"><img src="TWITTER ICON IMAGE PATH" alt=""></a>
```

Comment: Thanks it helped. My final code for twit link is    <a class="twitter-share-button shareButton twitter popup" href="http://twitter.com/share?text=I just entered the GOLD RUSH competition to win $10,000 Bullion! Enter now for your chance to win!&url=http://goo.gl/2Z58q9"  data-text="I just entered the GOLD RUSH competition to win $10,000 Bullion! Enter now for your chance to win!" data-count="none" data-url="https://www.facebook.com/DiscoveryChannelAU" title="TWEET" target="_blank"><img src="32919/images/twitter.png"  alt="" /></a>

Comment: This one helped. Thanks :)